# How to choose which column of my List in an ArrayList<List> to be used for sorting my ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compare

I want to sort my ArrayList containing a number of Lists. In other words, I have An ArrayList that I want to sort based on one of the elements of the inner List.
for instance Tags in the following list:
[[that, IN, 157], [that, WDT, 69], [that, DT, 33]]

I want to be able to choose which column should be used in sorting. I thought to use the below code. it does not, however, accept the input variable i for the inner method.

```
public void sortCheckedTags(int i){

    Collections.sort(checkedTags, new Comparator<List>(){
        public int compare(List  item1, List  item2)
        {
            return  ((String)item1.get(i)).compareTo(((String)item2.get(i)));
        }
    });
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your method like this:

```
public void sortCheckedTags(final int i)
```

You can see the documentation on [anonymous inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

> An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into a `switch` with 3 `case` statements, one for each field to be sorted, as you cannot override the method signature of the `compare` function since you are attempting to override Java's own `compare` method.

Then , at each case statement, use a different value for `i` i.e. 1, 2 or 3.